# How to Configure event key on kafka topic using source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

there is an existing kafka topic with a schema, and I want to stream events from another table with different properties  to the existing topic using transforms. I used renameField smt to avoid schema mismatch problems, but that didn't work.

I want to stream from postgreSql using debezium source connector

this is my configuration

```
{
    "name": "source-1",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.hostname": "********************",
    "database.user": "******************",
    "database.password": "*************",
    "database.dbname": "*************",
    "database.server.name": "**********",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "table.include.list": "public.table1",
    "column.include.list": "public.table1.transferId, public.table1.originSpaceId, public.table1.originalManuscriptId, public.table1.lastModifiedDate, public.table1.finalManuscriptId, public.table1.destinationSpaceId",
    "slot.name": "graphv1_table11",
    "publication.autocreate.mode": "filtered",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "*********:**************",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "**********",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "********:*******************",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "****************",
    "transforms": "RenameField,Reroute",
    "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.RenameField.renames": "public.table1.transferId:id, public.table1.originSpaceId:originalSpaceId, public.table1.originalManuscriptId:originalArticleId, public.table1.lastModifiedDate:modificationDate, public.table1.destinationSpaceId:finalSpaceId, public.table1.finalManuscriptId:finalArticleId",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": ".+",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "mydestinationTopic"

}
```

Comment: Sounds great. What exactly is the problem you're running into? Please show a [mcve] of your code and configurations

Comment: I used renameField smt  to comply with existing schema to avoid schema mismatch problems, but that didn't work,

Comment: What problems? Please show your config, as asked, and errors you're getting

Comment: I shared my configuration, hopefully to get some help

Comment: And what exactly is the error / stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: schema incompatibility was the error

Comment: Which table(s)? Which schema? Can you show the table schema and the Avro data it's trying to create? Did you already have a schema registered for that table? If not, I don't see why it would be incompatible. To literally answer the title of the question - ValueToKey transform is what you want, but that's not going to solve any schema problems

Comment: I have 2 tables say A,B with different schema differs only in column names and the data types are same, I thought it is possible to fit table  B  in the topic of table A, by renaming column names

Comment: Renaming fields won't change the namespace of the schema, which is likely the problem you're getting. But you need to show more information such as what's the existing schema and what is trying to be registered to be able to determine why they are incompatible or why your config is not working